# Is there an accessible library function to get the centroid of a set of UITouches?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html): If a `UIGestureRecognizer` is tracking multiple touches, `locationInView:` will (usually) return:

> ... the centroid of the touches involved in the gesture.

As far as I can see, if you're not using a gesture recognizer and instead are tracking touches directly through `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, etc., you can only ask each individual `UITouch` in `touches` for its `locationInView:`.

I could obviously iterate over all of the touches and calculate the centroid myself, but I'm guessing that there must be some iOS library function which would do this. Am I right, and is this function accessible? Alternatively, is there any other way of getting the same functionality or should I stop complaining and just calculate the centroid myself?

Comment: "or should I stop complaining and just calculate the centroid myself?", yes and that would not need more time to formulate your SO question

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, nothing provided by Apple.  Fairly straightforward to write...

```
// returns (0,0) if touches is nil or empty
-(CGPoint) centroidOfTouches:(NSSet *)touches inView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint centroid = CGPointZero, 
    curTouchPoint;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        curTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
        centroid.x += curTouchPoint.x;
        centroid.y += curTouchPoint.y;
    }
    centroid.x /= [touches count];
    centroid.y /= [touches count];
    return centroid;
}
```